# How to summarise the occurences of observation by an area in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe of crashes with different variables. I want investigate the count of what speed_limit has the most crashes. My df looks like:

[image: df]

The speed limit observations range from 10 - 110 in multiples of 10. I want to summarise the count of each one by creating a column for each using mutate(), then aggregating it by TA_code, TA_name using group_by(TA_code, TA_name).

Here is the direction I would like to go in (exapmle) :

```
crash <- st_read("df")

crash_speed <- crash %>%
  group_by(TA_code, TA_name) %>%
  mutate()   # then create new column for each speed interval summarising the counts of how many crashes have happened on each
```

I'm not really sure how to distinguish between each speed and summarise it by the TA's

Comment: It's a bit confusing. You want to group by `speed_limit` but instead you group by `TA_code` and `TA_name`. Do you want to know the count per speed limit per district perhaps? To answer the question in your first paragraph do `crash %>% group_by(speed_limit) %>% summarize(Crashes = n())`

Comment: yeah I want to find the count per speed limit per distrcit, sorry for confusion

Comment: in that case just add `speed_limit` in the `group_by()` you already have and then `summarize()` as I wrote above